# handling client side error from REST API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use `ajax()` and the result I got is a list of object array. When user pass invalid param, instead of the server side give me an invalid message it gave me fatal error (PHP). I have no control over the PHP, how should I catch if there's invalid respond?

I can't do `respond == 'undefined'`.

Comment: you tried with `typeof respond === "undefined"`?

Comment: @wZVanG it doesn't work coz error at the back will return string like <b>fatal error etc..

Comment: It sounds like only a successful response is deserialized as an array. If that is the case, you can check if the deserialized response's type, and consider it successful only if it is an array. if (response instanceof Array) { .. success .. }    If you are using $.ajax in jquery to make the call, you can specify dataType: 'json' and if it fails to parse, your error callback will be invoked. If you are deserializing the json another way, perhaps it throws an error on failure to parse and you can implement a try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using $.ajax() of jQuery?

```
$.ajax({ 
 url: 'myphpfile.php',
 type: 'get',
 datatype: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
  alert('No PHP file error');
 }
// now with error handling
,error {
 alert('PHP file error');
}

});
```